# WiX SQL Install

Tags: sql, wix

SQL Programmers:

I need to see how you used **WiX** to execute a collection of SQL files to the server.  The files are to be specified in a separate fragment, auto-generated by heat.

The installer does not need to install these SQL files on the target machine, just execute them. (However it would not be a problem if they were installed.)

I also would like to see the error messages (logs) from these executions if possible.  I don't see any logging functionality in the WiX SqlExtension.

For starters, I'm trying to use [Neil Sleightholm's](http://neilsleightholm.blogspot.com/2008/08/executing-sqlcmd-from-wix.html) idea, because it provides logging. Then extend that to dozens of files from heat.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [SqlScript element](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_sqlscript.htm) in the WiX toolset instead of sqlcmd.exe. Heat.exe will not be able to generate all this for you, you'll need to author the SqlScript elements by hand.